# Moving Generated Files in Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script that makes calls to some other scripts that generate some files. At the end of my shell script I want to move all files generated (they have the same preffix) into a folder.

However, for some reason, if I have the `mv` call at the end of the script I am getting this error, like the filesystem still didn't know about the files I think.

```
mv: cannot stat `foo_*': No such file or directory
```

My first attempt to "solve" this was to introduce a `sleep` call of some seconds to help me avoid this issue, but, even though the value was very high and I was sure the files were already created, I was getting the same error.

I then tried running my script like this:

```
sh myscript.sh ; mv foo_* bar
```

and it workded with no problem.

Any idea why this happens and how I can avoid having to use two scripts or a double line command to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I am writing this for someone that might get here from Google and have a similar problem.

Basically, I was generating the `mv` command like this:

`mv $preffix"_*" $destination`

For some reason, that wasn't working properly. Just created a temp variable like this:

`MV_CMD=$preffix"_*" $destination`

and then just called it like this:

`mv $MV_CMD`.

If anyone knows a cleaner way, please feel free to answer with that. Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: I can't envisage what the end of your script looks like that it runs into the problem.  Can you show some minimal version of your script that shows the problem?  Is the difference between `foo_*` and `foo*` significant?

Comment: Does `myscript.sh` change the current working directory?  If so, the script might not be executing the `mv` command from the directory that you expect it to (which would explain why running it as a separate command would work).

Comment: ... or do `mv /your/dir/foo*`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that was a minor typo, already corrected it on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes, instead of appending `sleep` followed by `mv` to the end of the script, add:

```
pwd
ls -la .
```

This will print the current directory and all it's contents to the console.

Additionally, execute your script with debugging enabled: `sh -x ./myscript.sh` to view all the commands executed to give you a better idea of what the cause could be, as well as what the files being created are, and in which directory.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I clearly still have a lot to learn about shell scripting.

Comment: Found out the problem, your tips helped debugging it. Basically, I was generating the command in the wrong way somehow, since, if I hard coded it, it was working with no problem. I had something like this `mv $preffix"_*" $destination`. Instead, just assigned that to a variable and did `mv $mymvcmd` and worked straight away.

Comment: If you know of a cleaner better way to "solve" this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @nunos try this `mv ${preffix}_* $destination`

Answer (score 0):

Its a common practice to not leave behind garbage, that your prog creates

check the other shells for rm command ....... they might have instructions to remove or delete the intermediate files created .

you should also check for specific directory changes , the files might have been created in some other locations or moved somewhere.

but in either case you need to just browse through the scripts looking for a rm , mv or a cd command.

that ought to do it.